# How can I dump the last row of a table?

Tags: sqlmap

Now in order to be familiar with a site's table , I need to dump the last row of a table named "account" . can you please tell me what parameters I can use to dump only the last row of a certain table? Here is the command I'm using for table dump . How should I modify it ?

```
screen python sqlmap.py -u 'URL' --identify-waf --tamper=between,randomcase,space2comment -v 3 --random-agent --level 3 risk 3 -D script -T account --dump
```

Comment: That takes an incredible amount of processing because it has to work out what the last possible row could be. It is far easier to output the entire table.

Comment: Is there any easy way to get an specific row in a table that would work fast ?

Comment: Well, first, you need to understand SQL. Your SQLmap command is just an info gathering statement. Do you know how to use SQLmap to run queries and do you know SQL?

Comment: I don't think this question belongs in security

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the 'last' row represents, assuming this is the most recently added record and provided you can run ad hoc queries through an injection point you could run a query like `select max(id) from table`, and then `select * from table where id=123456` or whatever value you get. There is a good chance that the table has an ID column or some other column you can use in your criteria. You can dump the **table structure** beforehand, for this the --columns option will come in handy.

And in fact, SQLmap has a --where option that you can use along with --dump:

> --where=DUMPWHERE   Use WHERE condition while table dumping

Check the manual, there is more than one way to achieve what you want.